# CUDA function call from anther cu file

Tags: cuda

I have two cuda files say A and B.
I need to call a function from A to B like..

```
__device__ int add(int a, int b) //this is a function in A
{
   return a+b;
}



__device__ void fun1(int a, int b) //this is a function in B
{
    int c = A.add(a,b);
}
```

How can I do this??

Can I use static keyword? Please give me an example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. CUDA only supports internal linkage, thus everything needed to compile a kernel must be defined within the same translation unit.

What you might be able to do is put the functions into a header file like this:

```
// Both functions in func.cuh
#pragma once
__device__ inline int add(int a, int b) 
{
   return a+b;
}

__device__ inline void fun1(int a, int b)
{
    int c = add(a,b);
}
```

and include that header file into each .cu file you need to use the functions. The CUDA built chain seems to honour the `inline` keyword and that sort of declaration won't generate duplicate symbols on any of the CUDA platforms I use (which doesn't include Windows). I am not sure whether it is intended to work or not, so *cavaet emptor*.

Answer (score 1):

I think meanwhile there is a possibilty to solve it:
[CUDA external class linkage and unresolved extern function in ptxas file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188527/cuda-external-class-linkage-and-unresolved-extern-function-in-ptxas-file)

You can enable "Generate Relocateable Device Code" in VS Project Properies->CUDA C/C++->Common or use compiler parameter -rdc=true.