# CUDA external class linkage and unresolved extern function in ptxas file

Tags: c++, class, cuda, unresolved-external

I'm working with CUDA and I have created an `int2_` class to deal with complex integer numbers.

Class declarations in the `ComplexTypes.h` file as follows:

```
namespace LibraryNameSpace
{
    class int2_ {

        public:
            int x;
            int y;

            // Constructors
            __host__ __device__ int2_(const int,const int);
            __host__ __device__ int2_();
            // etc.

            // Equalities with other types      
            __host__ __device__ const int2_& operator=(const int);
            __host__ __device__ const int2_& operator=(const float);
            // etc.

    };
}
```

Class implementations in the `ComplexTypes.cpp` file as follows:

```
#include "ComplexTypes.h"

__host__ __device__         LibraryNameSpace::int2_::int2_(const int x_,const int y_)           { x=x_; y=y_;}
__host__ __device__         LibraryNameSpace::int2_::int2_() {}
// etc.

__host__ __device__ const   LibraryNameSpace::int2_& LibraryNameSpace::int2_::operator=(const int a)                        { x = a;            y = 0.;             return *this; }
__host__ __device__ const   LibraryNameSpace::int2_& LibraryNameSpace::int2_::operator=(const float a)                      { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;             return *this; }
// etc.
```

Everything works well. In the `main` (which includes `ComplexTypes.h`) I could deal with `int2_` numbers.

In the `CudaMatrix.cu` file, I'm now including `ComplexTypes.h` and defining and properly instantiating the `__global__` function:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
__global__ void evaluation_matrix(T1* data_, T2* ob, int NumElements)
{
    const int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i < NumElements) data_[i] = ob[i];
}

template __global__ void evaluation_matrix(LibraryNameSpace::int2_*,int*,int);
```

The situation of the `CudaMatrix.cu` file seems to be symmetric to the `main` function. Nevertheless, the compiler complains:

```
Error   19  error : Unresolved extern function '_ZN16LibraryNameSpace5int2_aSEi'    C:\Users\Documents\Project\Test\Testing_Files\ptxas simpleTest
```

Please, consider that:

1. Before moving the implementation to separate files, everything was working correctly when including both declarations and implementations in the `main` file.
2. The problematic instruction is `data_[i] = ob[i]`.

Anyone has an idea of what is going on?

Comment: presumably you don¨'t have a `ComplexTypes.cpp` file, but rather a `ComplexTypes.cu` file which you are passing to nvcc, otherwise the `__host__ __device__` shouldn't compile...

Comment: I have found a solution to my issue. I have posted it as an answer hoping that it could be useful to other users.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The procedure I have followed in my post above has two issues:

1. The `ComplexTypes.cpp` filename **must** be turned to `ComplexTypes.cu` so that `nvcc` could intercept the CUDA keywords `__device__` and `__host__`. This has been pointed out by Talonmies in his comment. Actually, before posting, I was already changing the filename from `.cpp` to `.cu`, but the compiler was complaining and showing the same error. Therefore, I was ingenuously stepping back;
2. In Visual Studio 2010, one has to use **View -> Property Pages; Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code -> Yes (-rdc=true)**. This is necessary for separate compilation. Indeed, at [NVIDIA CUDA Compiler Driver NVCC](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc), it is said that:

> CUDA works by embedding device code into host objects. In whole program compilation, it embeds executable device code into the host object.  In separate compilation, we embed relocatable device code into the host object, and run the device linker (nvlink) to link all the device code together.  The output of nvlink is then linked together with all the host objects by the host linker to form the final executable. The generation of **relocatable** vs executable device code is controlled by the **--relocatable-device-code={true,false}** option, which can be shortened to **–rdc={true,false}**.

Comment: Basically, you only have two choices - move all the device code into the same compilation unit, or use separate compilation. You answer is the latter, and it only works with CUDA 5.0 or newer. The former was the only way to structure CUDA applications before the linker was introduced.

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been chasing this problem for hours. (Also applies to CUDA 5.5 and VS2012)

Comment: In Nsight Eclipse, the option is available as the radio button "Separate compilation" under Project > Properties > Build > Settings > CUDA