# VS 2015 unresolved external symbol when linking extern CUDA C++ code from separate .cu files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda, linker, extern

I am working in Visual studio 2015. 
I am using cuda 8.0. 
My GPU supports compute capability 5.0 (GTX 960m) 
I have been writing my code following [nvidia guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).

**I am trying to perform cuda separate compilation (4 .cu files). To gain access to functions declared in different .cu files I am using extern declarations to `__device__` functions or `__global__` kernels but i keep getting following errors:**

```
1>GPU_Engine.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_45_tmpxft_00001e30_00000000_8_GPU_Engine_cpp1_ii_1b52ddad
1>cplx.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_00001150_00000000_8_cplx_cpp1_ii_I
1>basic.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_40_tmpxft_00002648_00000000_8_basic_cpp1_ii_1458022c
1>time_evolution.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_49_tmpxft_000022d0_00000000_8_time_evolution_cpp1_ii_df1c8d01
1>E:\0000_0003_Programs\Visual_Studio\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GPU_Engine\x64\Release\GPU_Engine.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

It looks to me like MSVC linking error not NVCC.

I have to point that I am using `--device-c` flags in VS properties of my .cu files.

I am also concerned about project properties > cuda Linker > command line. I can find there linkage command for only one cuda object file. And i am not sure is it ok.

```
# (Approximate command-line.  Settings inherited from host are not visible below.)
# (Please see the output window after a build for the full command-line)

"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o x64\Release\GPU_Engine.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi   "
```

**Simplified code:** 
I have 4 separate .cu files:

- **GPU_Engine.h + GPU_Engine.cu:** class definition (class member functions are using cuda kernels)
- **Cplx.h + Cplx.cu:** my complex type definition and support
- **basic.h + basic.cu:** basic functions of mathematical model of given physical system
- **time_evolution.h + time_evolution.cu:** specialized function for the model

**GPU_Engine.h:**

```
// nothing interesting...
```

**GPU_Engine.cu:**

```
// something before.

 __device__
double potential(int& i, int& j, int& k) {
// do something.
}

__global__
void kernel_hamiltonian(Cplx* d_out, Cplx* d_psi, Cplx* d_lap) {
// do something.
}

// something after.
```

**Cplx.h:**

```
// type definition.

extern __device__ __constant__
Cplx I; // imaginary unit

// Cplx math support.
```

**Cplx.cu:**

```
__device__ __constant__
Cplx I; // cudaMemcpyToSymbol() inside GPU_Engine.cu in "start-up" section of code.
```

**basic.h:**

```
// nothing interesting...
```

**basic.cu:**

```
// something before.

extern __global__
void kernel_hamiltonian

// something after.
```

**time_evolution.h:**

```
// nothing interesting...
```

**time_evolution.cu:**

```
// something before.

extern __device__
double potential(int& i, int& j, int& k)

// something after
```

Comment: ok i menaged to solve this problem. it was trivial...
see: [stackoverflow.com question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188527/cuda-external-class-linkage-and-unresolved-extern-function-in-ptxas-file)

Answer (score 1):

ok so the main idea behind separate compilation is to enable nvcc option `-rdc=true` not `--device-c` with is very weird because in cuda guide, makefile samples were concerned about `--device-c` + `--device-link`.